# Why are the polynomial rings $k[x]$ and $k[x,y]/\langle y-x^2 \rangle$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This is related to an exercise in Hartshorne's book which [people have previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100906/66856) asked about, but I feel that this particular point hasn't been answered in a very simple way.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $k[x]$ be the ring of polynomials of one variable over $k$ and let $k[x,y]$ be the ring of polynomials of two variables over $k$. How can we see the isomorphism
$$
k[x] \simeq k[x,y]/\langle y-x^2 \rangle,
$$
where $\langle y-x^2 \rangle$ is the ideal in $k[x,y]$ generated by $y-x^2$?

Comment: are you asking for a explicit construction of such isomorphism or just how can you intuitively notice that these two rings are isomorphic?

Comment: No need to assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: How about [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100930/99914), which seems to be very direct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$\phi: k[x,y]\to k[x],\;x\to x,\;\;y\to x^2,\text{ and expand accordingly}$$

or if you prefer: $\phi f(x,y):=f(x,x^2)$. Now check stuff.

Comment: It's easy to see that $\phi$ is indeed a homomorphism. Any tips on how to see it's an isomorphism too?

Comment: @Pedro ¿Ahorrando signos, Pedro? La verdad no le veo mucho caso. Gracias, igual.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä  Oh, it is **not** an isomorphism, of course. What is its kernel? Well, now apply the first isomorphism theorem (for rings).\

Comment: ah, silly me. Thank you!

Comment: For the future reader: Details on the kernel of $\phi$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69026/66856).

Comment: @DonAntonio Los espacios antes de las comas no corresponden. ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let $D$ be a domain and $a \in D$. Then $D[y] \to D$ given by $f(y) \mapsto f(a)$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with kernel $\langle y-a \rangle$ because $f(y)=(y-a)q(y)+f(a)$. Apply this to $D=k[x]$.